# c# "==" operator : compiler behaviour with different structs

Tags: c#, .net

Code to illustrate :

```
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public int SomeNumber;
    }

    public string DoSomethingWithMyStruct(MyStruct s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            return "this can't happen";
        else
            return "ok";
    }

    private string DoSomethingWithDateTime(DateTime s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            return "this can't happen";  // XX
        else
            return "ok";
    }
```

Now, "DoSomethingWithStruct" fails to compile with : "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MyStruct' and '`<null>`'". This makes sense, since it doesn't make sense to try a reference comparison with a struct, which is a value type.

OTOH, "DoSomethingWithDateTime" compiles, but with compiler warning : "Unreachable code detected" at line marked "XX". Now, I'm assuming that there is no compiler error here, because the DateTime struct overloads the "==" operator. But how does the compiler know that the code is unreachable ? e.g. Does it look inside the code which overloads the "==" operator ? (This is using Visual Studio 2005 in case that makes a difference).

Note : I'm more curious than anything about the above. I don't usually try to use "==" to compare structs and nulls.

EDIT : I'll try to simplify my question - why does "DoSomethingWithDateTime" compile, when "DoSomethingWithMyStruct" does not. Both arguments are structs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It knows that a struct is never null (`Nullable<T>` aside); that is enough to emit the warning.

There is a known compiler issue in this area, that arose between the C# 2.0 compiler and the C# 3.0  compiler (and remains in the C# 4.0 compiler at the moment) [I'm not sure why you are seeing it on VS2005, though]. The equality test does not raise an unreachable-code warning for custom structs with `==` / `!=` operators. `DateTime` has these operators; your struct doesn't - hence the difference.

This issue is [logged on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/348850/c-3-net-3-5-version-of-csc-fails-to-report-cs0162-for-unrechable-code-struct-null), and has been looked at fairly recently by the compiler team (who are keen to fix it when opportunity arises).

Comment: Not sure I believe that's the reason.  `System.Int32` doesn't have an explicit `==` operator, and yet you can legally compare it to `null`...

Comment: @Aaronaught I did say "custom structs"... I'm excluding primitives here, since they have separate rules baked into the language itself.

Answer (score 2):

Because DateTime is a structure it cannot be null. And there is no way to override == operator for structure in such way that the second parameter will be null.

Answer (score 2):

As Hun1Ahpu said, it can never be null.

However, you could provide your own == operator, that could take an object as a parameter type that would allow the above code to compile.

Obviously, you would need it to do something logical.